# How does Rin's "Demon Fire" work?

Tags: blue-exorcist

He can use it to hurt people sometimes but, conveniently it doesn't hurt people when he does it on accident. Do they explain how this works at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rin can control the fire at will. He has used it multiple times throughout the series at will, burning only the things he wants and not burning the things he doesn't. If I remember correctly, it was shown both in anime and in the manga that Shura started training Rin to control his fire. The training was that he was given three candles and he was supposed to burn only the middle one. Rin continuously trained with the candles and eventually learned to control his fire.

After undergoing this training, I believe it was in chapter 26 of the manga when his fire was shown to be completely under his control in the Impure King Arc. This arc was not included in the anime.

Simply put, after some training, Rin can choose what he wants to burn with his fire and what he doesn't.

Comment: this is a good answer but I mean before the training like when he burned the clothes off of shura and yukio.

Comment: I suppose he wasn't really focusing on burning their clothes. But his fire got out of control anyway. It still showed that his fire only burned away their clothes very precisely and didn't did any damage to any of them. You can say it's just Rin's subconscious control of the fire.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you! I had been confused to how that works for a little while now.

Comment: You should read the manga if you haven't. It's a lot more detailed than the anime.